# Angular JS, set filter initial value inside of model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'd like to set some filter checkboxes as checked in an Angular JS app. I've tried using `ng-init` with `checked=true` but it isn't working as I'd expect.  I want to set all the checkboxes to initially be checked.

http://plnkr.co/edit/AtFGIyoo0h15XMl63aXK?p=preview

I'm fairly new to this but have had a go trying to find the information I'm after.  So, now I'm sure that I need to set up the 'checkedness' by setting values inside of my model to begin with.  So (this is where I'm certainly totally wrong) I'm using:

```
$scope.location = ['rural', 'urban', 'coastal']
```

With checkboxes like so:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="location.rural" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">Rural</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="location.urban" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">Urban</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="location.coastal" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">Coastal</label>
<hr>
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="property_type.pub" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">pub</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="property_type.bandb" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">bandb</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="property_type.hotel" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">hotel</label>
```

Here it is in context:

```
propertyApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.properties = [
{
    title: "Sharrow Bay Hotel",
    location:['rural', 'coastal'],
    property_type: ['pub']
},

{
    title: "The Royal Oak Inn",
    location:['rural'],
    property_type: ['pub']
},

{
    title: "Scale Hill Cottages",
    location:['urban'],
    property_type: ['hotel']
},
];

$scope.location = ['rural', 'urban', 'coastal']

$scope.title = "Phone list";  
$scope.multiplier = 3;
$scope.isEmpty = function (obj) {
    return angular.equals({},obj); 
};
```

})

How do I make the checkboxes checked on init?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with the **ng-model** directives should refer to bools in your model and not strings. You can then just initialise these bools to true or false in your controller:

```
propertyApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.location = {
        rural: true,
        urban: true,
        coastal: true
    }

    $scope.property_type = {
        pub: true,
        bandb: true,
        hotel: true
    }
});
```

Also let angular work out what's pristine and dirty for you.